# Private static method vs. static method

Tags: php

I understand that `static` means that an object doesn't need to be instantiated for that property/method to be available. I also understand how this applies to private properties and methods and public methods.  What I'm trying to understand is what static private function gains you.  For example:

```
class Beer {
    static private $beertype = "IPA";

    private function getBeerType() {
            return self::$beertype;
    }

    static public function BeerInfo() {
            return self::getBeerType();
    }
}

print Beer::BeerInfo() . "\n";
```

The private method `getBeerType()` executes just fine without an instantiated object as long as it's being called from a static public method.  If a static public method has access to all private methods (static and non-static), what's the benefit of declaring a method static private?

With strict error reporting turned on, I do get the warning that I *should* make `getBeerType()` static, although it still lets me run the code.  And I did a little research and it seems like other languages (Java) will force you to declare a private method as static when called by a static public method.  Looks like PHP lets you get away with this.  Is there a way to force it to throw an error and *not execute*?

Comment: "What I'm trying to understand is what static private function gains you"
What do you mean? Your method is not static: `private function getBeerType()` where do you see static here?

Answer (score 41):

A static private method provides a way to hide static code from outside the class. This can be useful if several different methods (static or not) need to use it, i.e. code-reuse.

Static methods and static variables, sometimes called class methods and class variables, are a way of putting code and data into a kind of namespace. You could also think of class variables as variables attached to the class itself, of which there is (by definition) exactly one, instead of to instances of that class, of which there may be zero, one or many. Class methods and class variables can be useful in working with attributes that not just remain same in all instances, but actually *be* the same.

An example of a class variable is a database handler in an ORM entity object. All instances are their own object, but they all need access to the *same* database handler for loading and saving themselves.

Private versus public is a completely separate quality, which is I suspect what you're stumbling over. A private method cannot be called and private variables cannot be accessed from code outside the class. Private methods are usually used to implement "internal" logic on the object that must not be accessible from outside the object. This restriction can be needed by instance methods as well as class methods.

An example of a private class method could be in a factory method. There might be three factory calls for creating an object which might differ in parameters being supplied. Yet the bulk of the operation is the same. So it goes into a `private static` method that the non-private factory methods call.

Comment: Hmmm, I still don't quite get it.  In my code above the non-static private method is "available" in the sense that it can be called from my static public method.  But since all private methods need to be called by a public method, I still don't see how anything is gained by explicitly declaring it static.I've tried it both ways, it works the same with no errors/warnings.

Comment: Visibility (private versus public) is different from class method (i.e. static) versus instance method (non-static). A private static method can be called from a public method - static or not - but not from outside the class.

Comment: I'm still wondering what the advantage is of declaring a private method as static.  If I declare it simply `private`, it can access/modify both static and non-static properties and be called by both static and non-static public (and private) methods.  But, if I declare it as `static private`, then I can't use the `this` operator (which wouldn't make sense) and thus can only modify static properties.  It would seem that by just declaring the method as `private` you get the best of both worlds.

Comment: If you need your method to access instance variables, then it is not a `static` method, whether or not it is `private`. If it is only for working on **non**-instance data, then it can be `static`. Private or public is a completely separate issue.

Comment: I guess I was just getting caught up in the explicit `static private` declaration for a method.  By leaving the static off, as long as the method is only accessing static properties, it's *implicityly* static.  As you say, in this case "it **can** be static", and probably should be declared so.

I think I get it now.  Thanks for being patient as I worked through this.

Answer (score 7):

> I understand static means that an object doesn't need to be instantiated for that property/method to be available.

Everything static just exists. Globally.

> I also understand how this applies to public properties and methods and public methods

Are you sure you have understood that it creates a global variable and a standard global function?

> What I'm trying to understand is what static private function gains you.

The *private* is just a specifier of [visibility<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). So that gains you visibility control.

Is it useful? Depends on the use-case.

Answer (score 5):

it's for preventing OTHERS from consuming it.

Example, you have a `Logger` static object, then you have two public static methods `LogOk` and `LogError` and both benefeit from an "internal" method `Log` but you don't want the consumers of that class to be able to call `Log` directly.

You can call `Logger::LogOk( "All right." );` but you cannot call `Logger::Log( "abc" );` if `Log` is private.

You you can internally always make use of it from the same class.

Comment: Then why do you need to make `Log` a `private static function` if it only for internal use? Why not just `private function` ?

Comment: Because if it was not static, it could not be called unless there exists an instance of the class. If `private static function Log()` was called **only** from **non-static** public methods then it is for sure that an instance exists (otherwise the non-static method could not be called). In this case it could just be `public function Log()`. Nevertheless if the wrapper around the private static method is also static (for example `public static function LogError()` then any consumer can call `LogError()` without an instance. If `Log` was not static it could not be called.

Comment: In any case, this is the "technical answer". I'm a deep defender **against** using static things. Static methods are **devil** and in fact -for me- there should only be non-static methods and for the consumer use the services from a service instance (typically a singleton, not necessarily, though) injected into the consumer via Dependency Injection (probably in the constructor). But this is not the topic of the question.

Answer (score 4):

Although the code works, it throws a Strict standards error:

> Strict standards: Non-static method Beer::getBeerType() should not be
>   called statically

So, here you get the use of the `private static`.

Comment: OK, I turned on STRICT error reporting and I do see those warnings now.

Answer (score 4):

Simply said you can declare a `private static function` if you have a repeated operation in  some of the `public static` functions in the class.

Naturally if you are an inexperienced programmer or new to the OOP putting **limitations** to your code seem strange. But strict declarations like this will make your code cleaner and easier to maintain.
In large projects and complex classes you can appreciate to know **exactly** what to expect from a function and **exactly** how  you can use it.

Here is a good read: [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and 
[God Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you can simplify this by doing the following.

```
static private $beertype = "IPA";

static public function BeerInfo() {
   return self::$beertype;
}
```

'static' purely means resident in a single region of memory.  If you are memory conscious, static implementations are a good strategy.

When you use a public static function, chances are, most of the time, that you don't want to deal with an instance of that class, but want to re-use pre-existing functionality from within that class.  Leveraging private static functions is the way to do that without instances.

However, you could have a public static function which accepts an argument which is an instance of said class, e.g.

```
static public function doSomething(Beer &$ref) {
   $ref->instanceLevelFunction(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the rule and the best answer,

static methods cannot access non-static variables and methods, since these require an instance of the class. Don't worry about the warning, the rule is set and it will break your code in the future once it's fully enforced. That is why

```
static public function BeerInfo() {
            return self::getBeerType()
```

is wrong,

you have to declare getBeerType as static.